# How to access javascript outside of django project?

Tags: django

I have become the owner of an older webapp that uses django and esri/jsapi3.28.  I am trying to reconstruct it in development environment.  It works in production using apache2 with document root at the 'webapp' directory.  I would like to create a development environment w/o apache2 and instead use django's runserver.  But when trying to test in development using runserver, it cannot find the 'my_ext_js' directory. I believe this is because the document root is different?  It appears I cannot change the document root.

This is the webapp structure.

```
webapp
  my_ext_js
    start.js
  django_app
    myapp
    django_app
```

Again, in production, we run apache2 with mod_wsgi and document root is webapp.
When running in development, I start runserver in django_app directory

```
django_app> python manage.py runserver
```

how can I run this using runserver in development and have it recognize/see the 'my_ext_js' folder?
The production code does not have the 'my_ext_js' in a static folder.  The html script just calls:

```
<script src="/my_ext_js/start.js"></script>
```

Any help would be great!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change [`STATICFILES_DIRS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATICFILES_DIRS) to include that directory for local development.

Comment: I have tried that and it still could not find.  The current webapp does not have it in their STATICFILES_DIRS either.